# await for getCurrentPosition() is not working

Tags: javascript, api

I'm writing click event on button to get localisation using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() to later fetch from openweathermap.org using longitude and latitude I have just got.
My problem is, I cannot find the way for my code to wait to recieve coordinates, and then make a fetch, which leads to errors because link to fetch from is invalid. I know I should make a function await, but I have completly no clue how to make that.

```
locate.addEventListener("click", function () {
    locateButtonFetch();
})
async function getLongAndLat() {
    //i have tried to make that await for onSuccess result, but I don't know how
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

var onSuccess = async function (position) {
    //that array is ofc global
    localisationCords[0] = position.coords.latitude;
    localisationCords[1] = position.coords.longitude;
};

function onError(error) {
    alert('Error: ' + error.message);
}
const locateButtonFetch = async () => {
    await getLongAndLat();
    console.log(localisationCords[0] + " + " + localisationCords[1]); //this logs undefined + undefined
    link = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=" + localisationCords[0] + "&lon=" + localisationCords[1] + "&exclude=daily&appid={myOWApi key}&units=metric";
    await fetch(link)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function (data) {
            future = data;
            console.log(future);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

I'm definitly missing something, but all the posts on this forum I have found havent solved my problem, nor my tries to modify these.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to add async-await in that

locate.addEventListener("click", async function () {
    await locateButtonFetch();
})

Comment: Its working now, but only after the second click, the first one shows the same error

Comment: you have tried this   locate.addEventListener("click", async function () { await locateButtonFetch(); })

Comment: @JayParmar Yes I did, it sadly still don't work from first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem you've got is `getLongAndLat()` is not set up to work with `await`. It returns an implicit promise (caused by the `async` prefix) but not one that's resolved only when the location has been granted (or denied). Since `getCurrentPosition()` doesn't return a promise, we'll need to handle the promise manually, ourselves.

Try this:

```
locate.addEventListener("click", locateButtonFetch);

function getLongAndLat() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject)
    );
}

const locateButtonFetch = async () => {
    try {
        let position = await getLongAndLat(),
            { coords } = position,
            url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat="+coords.latitude+"&lon="+coords.longitude+"&exclude=daily&appid={myOWApi key}&units=metric";
        await fetch(url)
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => {
                let future = data;
                console.log(future);
            })
            .catch(e => console.log(error));
    } catch(e) {
        alert('Error: '+e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working perfectly, thank You very much. That was my main suspect, but I had no clue how to fix that. Guess I'll need to work more on promises :)

Comment: If you'll forgive the plug, I have in-depth guides to both [promises](https://mitya.uk/articles/javascript-promises-part-1) and [async/await](https://mitya.uk/articles/javascript-async-await-part-1).